# System.InvalidCastException adding WMI objects to Dictionary

Tags: c#, binding, dictionary, combobox, wmi

I have two questions:

First, I'm struggling to add a few WMI objects into a dictionary. Currently, whenever I try to add the required values I'm getting `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` How can I correct this issue?

Second, after adding these WMI objects/values into my dictionary, how can I bind my dictionary to a WPF combobox? I'd like to be able to bind the dictionary values, in this case `NetConnectionID` to the combobox drop down while returning the `Index` from my dictionary whenever its corresponding value is selected.

Here is my code:

```
class NetworkInterfaces
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> GetNetworkAdapters()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Adapters = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                ("SELECT Index,NetConnectionID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
            ManagementObjectCollection data = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject item in data)
                Adapters.Add((int)item["Index"], (string)item["NetConnectionID"]);

            return Adapters;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

. . . .

    private void NetworkAdapters()
    {
        NetworkInterfaces NICInfo = new NetworkInterfaces();
        Dictionary<int, string> Adapters = NICInfo.GetNetworkAdapters();

        if (Adapters != null)
        {                
            cmbNetworkAdapters.ItemsSource = Adapters;
            cmbNetworkAdapters.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        }
    }

    private void cmbNetworkAdapters_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbNetworkAdapters.DisplayMemberPath = "Key";
    }

    private void cmbNetworkAdapters_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbNetworkAdapters.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    }
```

Error Details:

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=MyProject
  StackTrace:
       at MyProject.NetworkInterfaces.GetNetworkAdapters() in h:\_Storage\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\NetworkInterfaces.cs:line 28
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I would guess you're getting an invalid cast exception because one of your casts of `item[]` is invalid. You should verify the types for both lookups using the debugger (although usually the exception will tell you what the source type is anyway.)

Comment: When  you get an InvalidCastException, take a look at your casts. Is `item["NetConnectionID"]` always a string?

Comment: changing `item["Index"]` to `Convert.ToInt32(item["Index"])` seems to have resolved the exception but I'm still not sure how to get the dictionary 'key' or 'Index' while listing the 'value' or 'NetConnectionID' in the actual combobox. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Nevermind... Just needed to add `cmbNetworkAdapters.SelectedValuePath="Key"` and make a few adjustments to the `DisplayMemberPath` and I'm all set. Thanks for all the help!